# EF 4.1: Different ModelHashes when Running on Build Server VS Dev Server

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I am running some unit tests against the exact same binaries on my Build server, and on my Dev Server.  Some of my tests write to the DB, so when I check in, if needed, the DB gets rebuilt by the EF.  This has worked great for months.  Today we noticed that when we fire up the App in Dev, EF again tries to rebuild the database.  I realized after some investigation that the DB tear-down and rebuild on the Build box is creating a DB with one hash, and the DB rebuild from the Dev server is creating a DB with another (different) hash.

Both environments are running against the same database.  It would not make much difference except that my build server also deploys a couple of stored procedures.  These stored procedures get blown away when the Dev server fires up and drops the database.

However, there is a broader issue here, since I clearly don't understand what affects the ModelHash in the EdmMetadata table.  I thought it was based on the actual binaries, but it has to be more than that.  I am running the exact same binaries on both machines.

When the different enviornments create the database, these are their ModelHash:

```
BuildBox: 3E..FA
Local:    3E..FA
Dev:      99..58
```

Note that my local machine and the build box match.  This is completely repeatable.  Does anyone know what might be going on here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two environments were using slightly different versions of EF.  My build box was using the pre-release.  Dev was using the RTF.  Even though they were both EF 4.1, they were different builds, and cranked out different ModelHash codes.

I installed the RTF on all environments, and now they all produce the same ModelHash.